# Getting Input Value Issue JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to debug my JS program but I am unable to remedy the issue. I have tracked down the location of the bug. Two of my variables are not getting the input from an HTML form. I have checked the syntax and tried everything I can think of. When I console.log my input variables they are an empty string. When I hard code the input into the program it works as intended. The issue seems to be grabbing the input from the HTML document.
Heres my HTML Markup:

```
<form>
  <label for="message">Enter Your Message to be Encrypted:</label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="msg">
  <label for="key">Enter Your Encryption Key:</label>
  <input type="text" name="key" placeholder="Value Between 1-26" id="encrypt-key">
  <button type="button">Encrypt</button>
</form>
```

Heres my JS code:

```
(function(){
    let aplhabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
    let msg = document.getElementById('msg').value;
    let encryptKey = document.getElementById('encrypt-key').value;
    //let msg = "ab ab";
    //let encryptKey = "1";
    let msgArray = msg.split(' ');
    let encryptedMsgArr = [];

    function encryptWord() {
       msgArray.forEach(word => {
            let i;
            let array = [];
            for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
                var encryptedLetter;
                let letter = word.charAt(i);
                let aplhabetNum = aplhabet.indexOf(letter);
                let e = aplhabetNum + parseInt(encryptKey);
                if ( e > 25) {
                    e = e - 25;
                    encryptedLetter = aplhabet[e];
                } else {
                    encryptedLetter = aplhabet[e];
                }
                array.push(encryptedLetter);
            }
             let newWord = array.join('');
             encryptedMsgArr.push(newWord);
        });

        let encryptedMsg = encryptedMsgArr.join(' ');
        console.log(msg);
        alert(`The encrypted message is "${encryptedMsg}" and the decryption key is ${encryptKey}.`)

    }

    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', encryptWord);
})()
```

Thanks in advance for you guys help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are assigning the values for the variables `msg`, `encryptKey`, and `msgArray` **outside** the function. This means that their values are assigned **at runtime** (when your IIFE is evaluated) and not when the button is clicked.

Simply move these three `let` declarations/assignment into the function itself and your problem is solved:

```js
(function() {
  let aplhabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  let encryptedMsgArr = [];

  function encryptWord() {

    // These three variables have been moved into the function
    let msg = document.getElementById('msg').value;
    let msgArray = msg.split(' ');
    let encryptKey = document.getElementById('encrypt-key').value;

    msgArray.forEach(word => {
      let i;
      let array = [];
      for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        var encryptedLetter;
        let letter = word.charAt(i);
        let aplhabetNum = aplhabet.indexOf(letter);
        let e = aplhabetNum + parseInt(encryptKey);
        if (e > 25) {
          e = e - 25;
          encryptedLetter = aplhabet[e];
        } else {
          encryptedLetter = aplhabet[e];
        }
        array.push(encryptedLetter);
      }
      let newWord = array.join('');
      encryptedMsgArr.push(newWord);
    });

    let encryptedMsg = encryptedMsgArr.join(' ');
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(`The encrypted message is "${encryptedMsg}" and the decryption key is ${encryptKey}.`)

  }

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', encryptWord);
})()
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="message">Enter Your Message to be Encrypted:</label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="msg">
  <label for="key">Enter Your Encryption Key:</label>
  <input type="text" name="key" placeholder="Value Between 1-26" id="encrypt-key">
  <button type="button">Encrypt</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, Terry, That makes sense. I had not realized that I was assigning the variables at runtime. Thank you for your help!